# getting red line in files after upgrading to gradle 4.4 and gradle build tools version 3.1.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

The Android studio ask me to update the gradle version to 4.4 and gradle build tool version to 3.1.2.
After the update, The whole android studio shows red lines in file, when I hover my cursor on these error it says "cannot resolve symbol" but compiles with no error i.e., build is successful.[Click here to see red lines in java files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyehj.png)

and Here are the gradle app and project files.

```
//Build.gradle(project)
//Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

        jcenter()
        maven {

            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and

```
//build.gradle(module:app)
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.developers.paras.droidwatch"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 9
        versionName "9.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Things I have already tried.

1. Clean and Rebuild.
2. Invalidate Cache and Restart.
3. Updating gradle version to 4.9.
4. Setting local gradle for the project.

See my gradle logs here https://drive.google.com/open?id=18bFZdkWX4AFPfpmfjvN1t80WpVRpiHWs

See even release build is generated after these errors. [Release apk generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi1Oo.png)

**Update** : Recently after Reinstalling Studio, I've created a new project and everything works fine. No errors for "cannot resolve symbol".

Comment: 1st you change `compile` to `implement` then Clean, Rebuild

Comment: I did as what you said, but still getting errors everywhere "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: Your Gradle build Successfully complete ????...

Comment: If gradle build is successful, then try clean, rebuild, or restart if that does not work. That's all you can do with internal errors.

Comment: I have done invalidating cache and restart, changing gradle version but nothing works.

Comment: You should share the Gradle warnings which are presented as text in one of the studio panels.

Comment: I have added drive link to gradle logs.

Comment: Please put all relevant information directly into the question. Don't use links to external resources (they tend to break after some time, which makes the question useless for future visitors).

Comment: I don't have reputations for that.

Answer (score 0):

not the most graceful solution in the world but deleting and re-cloning the project was the fastest way to resolve this for me.

if you're not using git... well. now is a good time to start.

I tried deleting and re-syncing all the various config files and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Well It is resolved by reinstalling android studio. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I got into similar situation: upgraded Gradle to 4.4, then opened a former porject which had been built with Gradle 3.1.2.

Android Studio noticed it and generously offered:

> To take advantage of all the latest features (such as Instant Run), improvements and security fixes, we strongly recommend that you update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.1.2 and Gradle to version 4.4.

When I choose to update, I got the red underlines showing errors everywhere in MainActivity.java, however the project was building and runnig perfectly.

I also tried to rebuild and to invalidate cache & restart, but had no success.

For me, editing the *build.gradle (module:app)* file helped.
When I modified both `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to the latest (27) and changed the version number of line `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:2x.x.x'` under dependencies to the latest, then resynced, the red lines suddenly disappeared from MainActivity.java and everything became normal.

Maybe not the fiddling with sdk version numbers are important here, but to force a proper gradle resync.

Please note also, that since Gradle 3.4, under dependencies in *build.gradle* file some configuration words changed: `compile`, `testCompile`, `androidTestCompile`, `testApi`, `androidTestApi` become obsolete and should be replaced with `implementation` or `api`.

You can find more on this issue here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration?utm_source=android-studio#new_configurations and a proper explanation on the difference between choosing `implementation` or `api` here: https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa